# RadioButton ngmodel not working for boolean values

Tags: angular, radio-button, boolean, angular2-ngmodel

I have two radio buttons in Sample with ngModel.

```
<div id="container">
    <input type="radio" id="radiobuttonstoerung1" label="Blinkend" name="stoerungBlinkend" [(ngModel)]="project.modelvalue"
          value="true"/>
    <input type="radio" id="radiobuttonstoerung2"  label="Dauersignal" name="stoerungBlinkend" [(ngModel)]="project.modelvalue"
  value="false"/>
</div>
```

When I passed the boolean variable it is not working.

```
export class RadioButtonController implements OnInit {
    project = { modelvalue: true };
}
```

*Sample Link:* https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-cxt8bs-quvb7y?file=radiobutton.html

*Scenario* when I passed 'stoerungBlinkend' as true, RadioButton with value="true" should be checked. If I passed it as false, then RadioButton with value ="false" should be checked.

I have found the workaround solution, but could anybody explain in detail why the above scenario is not working?

Comment: What is the behavior that you expected? And what is the actual result? Please describe precisely

Answer (score 17, accepted):

As explained in the Angular [documentation](https://angular.io/guide/template-syntax#remember-the-brackets), when you set the radio button value with `value="true"`, you actually set the value to the string `"true"`, which is not identical to the boolean `true`.

To set a boolean value on the input element, use property binding with `[value]="true"`:

```
<input type="radio" ... [(ngModel)]="project.stoerungBlinkend" [value]="true" />    
<input type="radio" ... [(ngModel)]="project.stoerungBlinkend" [value]="false" />
```

See [this stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ggkfyz) for a demo.

Answer (score 0):

Try something like this:

Your TS:

```
    form: FormGroup;
constructor(fb: FormBuilder) {
    this.name = 'Angular2'
    this.form = fb.group({
            gender: ['', Validators.required]
});
}
```

HTML:

```
<form [formGroup]="form">
    <input type="radio" value='Male' formControlName="gender" >Male
    <input type="radio" value='Female' formControlName="gender">Female
</form>
```